# Can't get Chronometer within fragment to start in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a stopwatch in one of my fragments but I'm am unable to get the stopwatch to start. Ideally it would start after pressing startButton but I can't even get the start() function to work at all. Right now this is what I have:

Fragment:

```
    public class RunFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Chronometer sChronometer;
    private long pauseOffset;
    private boolean running;
    Button startRun;
    Button pauseRun;
    Button stopRun;


    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public RunFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void disable(View startButton){


    }



    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment RunFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static RunFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        RunFragment fragment = new RunFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_run, container, false);

        Button startRun = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.startRun);
        Button pauseRun = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.pauseRun);
        Button stopRun = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.stopRun);
        sChronometer = (Chronometer) v.findViewById(R.id.sChronometer);
        startRun.setOnClickListener(this);
        pauseRun.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopRun.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.startRun:
                sChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                sChronometer.start();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "startRun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.pauseRun:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "pauseRun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.stopRun:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "stopRun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }

    }
```

I'm not receiving any errors and the Toasts are showing up so I'm not sure what the problem is.
Here is the xml code:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    tools:context=".RunFragment">

    <data>
        <variable name="runLive" type="com.example.wam1.RunLive"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/startRun"
            android:onClick="startRun"
            android:text="Start" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/pauseRun"
            android:onClick="pauseRun"
            android:text="Pause" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/stopRun"
            android:onClick="stopRun"
            android:text="Stop" />



    </LinearLayout>


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="100dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:background="#f1f1f1"
        >
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Distance"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity= "center" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Heart Rate"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity= "center" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Pace"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity= "center" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{runLive.distance}"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity= "center"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="1dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{runLive.heartRate}"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity= "center"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{runLive.pace}"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity= "center"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recomendation"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"/>


    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/sChronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:format="00:00:00"
        android:textSize="35sp">

    </Chronometer>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please try Sarah Khan's suggestion (@Override) and let us know if it helps.  Please be sure to "upvote" and "accept" her answer if it resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

since you are implementing an interface 'View.onClickListener', you should define it's method onClick and not your own. That difference can be made from you not overriding the onClick method. Just change your onClick method to

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //super.onClick(view);

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.startRun:
                sChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                sChronometer.start();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "startRun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.pauseRun:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "pauseRun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.stopRun:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "stopRun", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }

    }
```